# Paracompact and countably compactly generated spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

A space X is *countably compactly generated* if it can be written as countable direct limit of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Are countably compactly generated spaces paracompact spaces? Do we have partition of unity for countably compactly generated spaces?

Comment: Are you assuming that the compact Hausdorff spaces that enter the colimit are themselves separable, or even second countable?

Comment: Asked already: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1047888/94514

Comment: If the final space is regular, the answer is yes: a countably compactly generated space is Lindelöf (or I am missing something ?), and a Lindelöf regular space is paracompact.